# TypeError: products.map is not a function. map function is not recognised

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, list

I want to render the list "products".Means there are 3 items in product array, I want to use map method to render this list. But getting TypeError: products.map is not a function

```
const products = [
  {
    id: 101,
    name: "Skirt",
    image: "https://i.pravatar.cc/48?u=118836",
    price: 700,
  },
  {
    id: 102,
    name: "Jeans",
    image: "https://i.pravatar.cc/48?u=933372",
    price: 1500,
  },
  {
    id: 103,
    name: "Top",
    image: "https://i.pravatar.cc/48?u=499476",
    price: 1000,
  },
];
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <RetriveProducts products={products} />
    </div>
  );
}
function RetriveProducts(products) {
  return (
    <div>
      {products.map((product) => {
        <ProductList
          image={product.image}
          name={product.name}
          price={product.price}
        />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

function ProductList(image, name, price) {
  return (
    <div>
      <img src={image} alt={name} />
      <h2>{name}</h2>
      <span>{price}</span>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

I have also used forEach method but still getting the same issue.
Earlier I have used same array with map function, it worked but not working in this code. If you have any solution please post it.

Comment: Are you sure it's not because you are loading `products` from an API and trying to run map on products before the call is completed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you're passing the `products` prop to the `RetriveProducts` component, so:

1. You will need to destructure the `props` object to access the `products` array.
2. You will need to use `key` prop<sup>***1***</sup>.
3. You would need to ***return*** the `ProductList` component.

   ```js
   {products.map((product) => {
       // First way
       return <ProductList
         key={product.id}
         image={product.image}
         name={product.name}
         price={product.price}
       />;
     })}
   ```

**SAMPLE CODE:**

```js
// ...rest of your code
function RetriveProducts({ products }) { // Destructure the props object to access the products array
  return (
    <div>
      {products.map((product) => ( // <--- Second way
        <ProductList
          key={product.id} /* <--- add a key prop to each child component */
          image={product.image}
          name={product.name}
          price={product.price}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>[Keeping List items in order with key](https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists#keeping-list-items-in-order-with-key)

Comment: Also note that this answer correctly changes the `{ }` around the `.map()` callback body with `( )`, to avoid the necessity of an explicit `return`. (A `return` would not of course be a terrible thing, but one or the other is necessary.)